# How to create mega menu with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-bootstrap, ant-design-pro

I am working on ecommerce web app with react/redux. I have two questions:

1. How do I create a mega menu like aws(https://aws.amazon.com )?
2. How do I display a category menu with sub categories filter on the left and content from the selected category with featured image thumbnail on the right similar to what they have on aws(https://aws.amazon.com )?

I am looking to use, either material UI, or Ant design or Material Bootstrap or any framework that can do that real well.

[image]

[image]

[image: With image]

Answer (score 2):

In Material UI, you could achieve this with the [Popper](https://material-ui.com/components/popper/) utility.

You could create a popper and give it a height and width of your desired "mega" size.

The basic Material UI Popper example is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    border: '1px solid',
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function SimplePopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        <div className={classes.paper}>The content of the Popper.</div>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could add width and height properties to the paper style class according to your desired size (below is simply an example -- you may want to use pixel/percentages):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        width: "50vh",
        height: 600,
        border: "1px solid",
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.